# Duvida Exercicio Collections - Interface Queue

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface, arraylist, collection

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida neste exercício sobre Collections em que Devo usar a interface Queue :

3. Escreva um programa que simule o controle de uma pista de decolagem de aviões em um aeroporto. Neste programa, o usuário deve ser capaz de realizar as seguintes tarefas: 
   a) Listar o número de aviões aguardando na fila de decolagem; 
   b) Autorizar a decolagem do primeiro avião da fila; 
   c) Adicionar um avião à fila de espera; 
   d) Listar todos os aviões na fila de espera; 
   e) Listar as características do primeiro avião da fila.

Considere que os aviões possuem um nome e um número inteiro como identificador. Adicione outras características conforme achar necessário.

Comecei meu código assim mas eu parei na questão "B", tenho duvidas se é necessário utilizar um método

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ControledeTrafego {

    private String nome;
    private int codigo;

    public ControledeTrafego(String nome, int codigo) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public void autorizacao(ControledeTrafego autorizacao){
        System.out.println("Favor comnfirmar a autorização do voo");
    }       
}
```

Este é o Programa :

```
package Exercicio3;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Controle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Queue<ControledeTrafego> aviao =  new LinkedList<>();

        ControledeTrafego aviao1 = new ControledeTrafego(" Tam ", 747);
        ControledeTrafego aviao2 = new ControledeTrafego(" Gol ", 737);
        ControledeTrafego aviao3 = new ControledeTrafego(" Azul", 722);

        aviao.add(aviao1);
        aviao.add(aviao2);
        aviao.add(aviao3);

        System.out.println("Numero de avioes na fila de embarque : " +aviao.size());    
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a diferença da fila de decolagem e fila de espera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de não entende o porquê de duas filas, a implementação seria algo da seguinte forma:

Classe `Aviao`:

```
public class Aviao {

  private String nome;
  private int codigo;

  public Aviao(String nome, int codigo) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.codigo = codigo;
  }

  public String getNome() {
    return nome;
  }

  public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }

  public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
  }

  public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
  }

  public void autorizacao(Aviao autorizacao) {
    System.out.println("Favor confirmar a autorização do vôo.");
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.getCodigo() + " - " + this.getNome();
  }
}
```

Classe `Controle`:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Controle {

  private final Queue<Aviao> espera = new LinkedList<>();

  public void listar() {
    System.out.println("============ LISTANDO ============");
    this.espera.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
  }

  public void listarPrimeiro() {
    System.out.println("============ PRIMEIRO ============");
    System.out.println(this.espera.element());
  }

  public void adicionar(Aviao aviao) {
    System.out.println("=========== ADICIONANDO ===========");
    System.out.println(aviao);
    this.espera.add(aviao);
  }

  public Aviao autorizarDecolagem() {
    Aviao aviao;

    aviao = this.espera.remove();
    System.out.println("====== AUTORIZANDO DECOLAGEM ======");
    System.out.println(aviao);

    return aviao;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Controle controle = new Controle();

    controle.adicionar(new Aviao("Tam", 747));
    controle.adicionar(new Aviao("Gol", 737));
    controle.adicionar(new Aviao("Azul", 722));

    controle.listar();
    controle.autorizarDecolagem();
    controle.listar();
  }
}
```

A saída gerada para esta implementação é a seguinte:

> ```
> =========== ADICIONANDO ===========
> 747 - Tam
> =========== ADICIONANDO ===========
> 737 - Gol
> =========== ADICIONANDO ===========
> 722 - Azul
> ============ LISTANDO ============
> 747 - Tam
> 737 - Gol
> 722 - Azul
> ====== AUTORIZANDO DECOLAGEM ======
> 747 - Tam
> ============ LISTANDO ============
> 737 - Gol
> 722 - Azul
> ```